# How to use IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo::GetInfo Method

Tags: c#, .net, api, com

How do I use the [IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo::GetInfo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387091.aspx)

I have referenced the WUApiLib but I cant find this interface anyhwere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WindowsUpdateAgentInfoClass WUAInfo = new WindowsUpdateAgentInfoClass();
(int)WUAInfo.GetInfo("ApiMajorVersion");
```